# Is it inefficient to use implicit struct creation (a.k.a. shorthand or literal notation) in function parameters?

Tags: coldfusion, struct, implicit

Bear with me on this...

Say I have an existing struct:

```
<cfset struct1 = {key1 = "foo", key2 = "bar"}>
```

...to which I want to add some key/value pairs. The typical approach would be something like:

```
<cfset struct1.key3 = "baz">
<cfset struct1.key4 = "qux">
<cfset struct1.key5 = "quux">
```

Alternatively, I could use structAppend():

```
<cfset struct2 = {key3 = "baz", key4 = "qux", key5 = "quux"}>
<cfset structAppend(struct1, struct2, false)>
```

... which has the added bonus of allowing me to control whether preexisting keys are overwritten. The disadvantage, I assume, is that it uses more memory since the new key/value pairs will end up existing in two different places. But what if I do this instead:

```
<cfset structAppend(struct1, {key3 = "baz", key4 = "qux", key5 = "quux"})>
```

Have I eliminated the extra memory usage? Or, will the second parameter's struct continue to exist in some secret location after the function has executed-- in which case I'm now wasting memory on a redundant set of keys/values that I can't even access.

Although my primary concern is memory usage, it probably wouldn't hurt to know if the last approach has any other disadvantages, such as processing overhead, compared to the first. And I realize that the differences in resource usage between any of the methods I presented will not be significant in a single execution scenario. I'm thinking on a larger scale, with lots of data and/or many repetitions.

I'm currently on CF 9.0.1, if that matters.

Comment: What do you not like about the typical approach?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the first approach (though the "OverwriteFlag" feature of StructAppend would certainly be an advantage in some cases). I'm mainly trying to learn what becomes of an implicit struct argument after the function to which it was passed is done executing. I would expect it to persist since structs are normally passed by reference. But that would leave you with an inaccessible struct still in memory, since its sole reference was in the function's arguments scope, which no longer exists. If that is indeed what happens, would it be garbage collected at some point?

Comment: I do wish CFML developers would learn what _implicit_ means. What you're using is **struct literal notation** and **it is explicit**.  You're specifically and directly saying "here is a struct". It's a shorthand method of struct creation (compared to the traditional way of doing it), and it can be used inline, but there's nothing _implied_ about it.

Comment: For an example of when CFML is implicit, consider when you have `<cfif len(trim(string)>` or `<cfset Two = '1' + '1' />` - those are both examples of implicit data conversion, because the conversion is implied by the context but not explicitly done, (as opposed to writing `x.toString()` or `Integer.valueOf(string)` which are explicit conversions).

Comment: Good to know. The term "implicit" never actually made sense to me in this context-- I was just imitating some CF guru or other whose blog I read. I have to admit, though, that I also don't understand how using curly brackets to define a struct is any more "literal" than using StructNew() + dot notation, but maybe I just need to think about it more deeply. I've always just use term "shorthand notation" when talking to colleagues, because everyone seems to understand it intuitively.

Comment: I think literal simply comes from where `a = 5` and `b = "something"` - those things are literally in the source code, rather than being derived in some way (function call or via operations). Using StructNew is building it in stages rather than a single syntax unit that is a struct, if that makes sense? In any case, yeah, calling it shorthand is accurate and understandable.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. I wonder if the mistaken use of the word "implicit" comes from the fact that, when using shorthand, you don't have to explicitly ask for a new struct (or array) to be created, because its creation is implied by the fact that you are defining its members. It actually does make sense now that I think about it, even though I now know it's wrong.

Comment: For the record, the official ColdFusion documentation frequently refers to structs and arrays defined in shorthand as "implicitly created structs/arrays". So-- in the CF universe at least-- this terminology apparently is correct after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the implicit struct will hang around in memory until the next GC decides it needs to be cleaned up. But it'll get created just the same with either of your `structAppend()` examples. The only difference is that the `struct2` reference never gets created if you do it inline.

I suppose if a GC happened in the middle of a request, the inline version would more quickly become a candidate to be cleaned up as there will - implicitly - be zero references still using it, whereas if you give it a name, there's a reference right there, and it won't be available for GC until after the end of the request when the reference itself gets destroyed.

Comment: The more I thought about it, the more inevitable it seemed that this would be the answer. The obvious follow-up questions would be: 1) does ColdFusion ever garbage collect a request's unreferenced variables while the request is still running; and 2) would forcing GC get rid of the unneeded struct?

Comment: The JVM doesn't concern itself with "requests": that's a web app consideration. So it'll just GC whenever it sees fit. I would say that if you come to need to force GCs, then you're almost certainly treating the symptom rather than the problem.

Comment: We have a scheduled task that used to cause out of memory errors until we split it into multiple "requests." I've assumed ever since that some sort of variable cleanup occurs when a request ends. Now that you've set me straight, I have even more questions, but I'll save them for other threads.