# Is it inefficient to use implicit array creation (a.k.a. shorthand or literal notation) in loops or function parameters?

Tags: arrays, performance, memory, coldfusion, implicit

(This is sort of a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690007) about structs)

Would this:

```
<cfset myArray = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfloop query="myQuery">
    <cfset myArray[1] = queryCol1>
    <cfset myArray[2] = queryCol2>
    <cfset myArray[3] = queryCol3>
    <cfset funcionWithArrayParam(myArray)>
</cfloop>
```

... use system resources more efficiently than this:

```
<cfloop query="myQuery">
    <cfset functionWithArrayParam([queryCol1, queryCol2, queryCol3])>
</cfloop>
```

?

And to keep the focus narrow, assume that the array in the first example serves no purpose other than to feed the function. Also, assume that the query and/or column data are large enough to make efficiency a worthwhile consideration.

The second method is tempting for its compactness, but my concern is that I'm not sure how many new arrays it's creating on each iteration. The first method creates one, I believe, due to the fact that arrays are passed by value in CF. But does that mean the second method creates two arrays (an implicitly created one, and a copy of it to use in the function)?

It would also be interesting to know how shorthand notation compares, performance-wise, to multiple cfset statements for populating an array. I realize it's not apples-to-apples since the former also creates the array, but still... I suppose I could easily test this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam Cameron technically answered my question in one of his comments, but since it wasn't his "official" answer, I'll provide my own (along with a little perspective).

The answer is: YES. It is, in fact, inefficient to use implicit array creation in the manner demonstrated in my second example. Does that mean you won't be able to get away with it most of the time? Of course not! But, I've presented two methods of performing the same operation, the second of which is **half as efficient** as the first in terms of memory usage (and even a tiny bit slower)-- in my world, that's worth knowing about! If you're still going to insist on using implicit array creation in that situation, it might not hurt to ask yourself why. Is it because you think compressing your code onto one line impresses the girl programmers? I guess that's *something*. "Readability" seems to be the most popular excuse, though (it is, after all, the *only* measure by which implicit array/struct creation is not objectively inferior to explicit) If, like me, you find readability to be an ambiguous, moving target, there's nothing wrong with letting efficiency influence how you code. If you know how to write an efficient algorithm, don't let the popular "premature optimization" hyperbole scare you into writing an inefficient one instead. That demonstrates a lack of perspective just as much as premature optimization does.

Answer (score 2):

Performance wise, the difference will be negligible, but implicit creation is usually slightly slower but implicit is far more readable which is more important long term unless you're dealing with some sort of massive scaling problem.

Edit: Wrote a quick test script, and I get completely different results. I'd say both are so close, it shouldn't matter, but run the test on your system.  I'm running this on a Macbook Pro with CF10, it may vary with your specific implementation. Maybe the resulting java byte output
might reveal any structural differences between the two methods.

```
<cfset iterations = 1000000>

<cfset start = getTickCount()>

<cfloop from="1" to="#iterations#" index="x">
    <cfset a[x] = arrayNew(1)>
    <cfset a[x][1] = x>
    <cfset a[x][2] = x>
    <cfset a[x][3] = x>
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>Explicit Array took: #getTickCount()-start#ms</cfoutput><br>

<cfset start = getTickCount()>
<cfloop from="1" to="#iterations#" index="y">
    <cfset b[y] = [y, y, y]>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>Implicit Array took: #getTickCount()-start#ms</cfoutput><br>
```

Comment: I would personally agree with your point about readability, but that's pretty subjective. In any case, when there are multiple ways to do something, it never hurts to know the advantages and disadvantages of each.

Comment: I ran the test myself, and I, too, am finding the implicit method to be slightly slower. For some reason, I was expecting the opposite.

Comment: I guess readability depends on the reader, because I find explicit to be more readable than implicit.

Comment: Both the reader, and the situation, I'd say. But I do prefer shorthand more often than not-- which may lead me to overuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Performance? Don't worry about it. Any test in which you need to loop-de-loop to amplify the duration of the operation under test so that said duration is measureable intrinsically demonstrates that the performance considerations are negligible.

As for how many arrays are getting created? In each example one array is being created in the calling code, then it is basically duplicated when passed into the function. So no real difference there.

It comes down to what you think is more maintainable (we an probably short-circuit subsequent questions you might have along these lines by stipulating that this will always be the answer).

Personally I think having separate statements for setting each array element is a bit clunky-looking when one can do it in one hit.

Comment: Why on earth would the calling code in my first example need to create an array that already exists?

Comment: The first code block *creates an array* with `arrayNew()`, and then populates it. The second code block *creates an array* with the array-literal notation (populating it @ the same time). Both code blocks create an array. Then irrespective of how the array was created, when passed to `functionWithArrayParam()` it will be duplicated.

Comment: Let me preface this by saying that *I know passing an array to a function creates a copy of it*. Believe me, I'm not suggesting that the 1st method avoids that somehow. Nor am I ignoring the fact that it has to create the array in the first place. What I *am* suggesting is that the 1st method creates **one** new array **per loop iteration**, and the 2nd method creates **two** new arrays **per loop iteration**. I think you might be overlooking the fact that the initial array creation occurs outside the loop in the 1st method.

Comment: I should also mention that my concerns here are based on the assumption that, if you're not careful how you use implicit array creation, it's possible (not necessarily *common*, but *possible*) to create a situation where you're spawning anonymous, single-use arrays

Comment: ... faster than GC can clean them up, which could lead to out of memory errors. Fortunately, I think you're just the man to tell me if that assumption is wrong.

Comment: Oh I see, right, yeah, didn't notice the loop positioning. So there would be a slight resource hit, but we're talking a few bytes, and RAM is measured in GB these days, so I don't think really it's worth worrying about as a matter of course. It's perhaps good to think about these things, but not to dwell on them too much. You'd need to be doing *really a lot* of looping for this sort of thing to matter, by which time you're gonna be looking at more significant resource pinch. Calling that function stacks of times is gonna be worse than the array consideration. Using an array *at all*...

Comment: ... is going to be more of a consideration than how the array is built... passing copies of it into the function. Perhaps it's better to put it in the REQUEST scope and access it via reference from within the function? Or wrap it in a struct? Or putting the loop *inside* the function, etc. But, firstly, just don't prematurely optimise. Deal with it if it becomes a problem. Otherwise it's not a good use of time.

Comment: Just ignore it till it becomes a problem? Are you a politician? (j/k) Seriously, though, I understand what you're saying. I do occasionally work on projects that involve unreasonably large amounts of data, which is why I'm trying to familiarize myself with any potential pitfalls that may exist in such scenarios, however "fringe" they may be. Could you clarify what you mean by "we're talking a few bytes"? The amount of data in the arrays would have a lot to do with how much memory you were wasting by creating twice as many copies of them, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well your array is not likely to hold MB after MB of string data, generally, I'd think? Numerics are pretty small, and most other stuff will just be references, which are only a few bytes. *an array* doesn't take up much space in general, I think. Obviously (?) if you are carting around truckloads of data, then you need to consider how you manage it, sure. That was why I mentioned the consideration that given arrays are copied by *value*, then that means the "truckloads of data" are also going to be copied. Recomment reading up on premature optimisation. This conversation[...]

Comment: [...] is now beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question comment thread, TBH. My contact details are in my profile if we need to continue it, or... I do pay attention to all questions tagged with ColdFusion (etc).